# What does the + mean in +a[i]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how some javascript code for creating pagination is working and I ran across this line:

```
if (+a[i].innerHTML === Pagination.page) a[i].className = 'current';
```

I was just wondering what the + is doing in this +a[i].  Here is the rest of that section of code just in case.

```
Bind: function() {
    var a = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (+a[i].innerHTML === Pagination.page) a[i].className = 'current';
        a[i].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Click, false);
    }
},
```

Comment: implicit conversion to `number`, it's like saying `0 + a[i].innerHTML` (but not exactly `+"abc" === NaN` `0+"abc" === "0abc"`)

Comment: its called *unary plus operator* => http://google.it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) operator:

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to convert it into a number, if it isn't already

For example

```
+"15" === 15
```

Answer (score 1):

It converts it to a number.

`+"234" => 234`